# No me deja Exportar

Tags: eclipse

al querer exportar el proyecto me sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no me deja exportarlo

Comment: El mensaje te dice el encoding que estas usando no soporta algunos carácteres, intenta poner algo de código para que te podamos ayudar, sino vamos a ciegas.

Comment: Ya esta, Muchas Gracias. Tenia un icono que no se podia poner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo cambiar la codificación de tu proyecto y eclipse a `UTF-8`.

**Proyecto**

Click derecho sobre el proyecto -> Propiedades -> Resources -> Ahí mismo veras para cambiar la codificación.

**Eclipse**

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace : Text file encoding
```

Es posible que al cambiarlo, se te pongan caracteres extraños en el código, simplemente ve cambiándolos, a la larga te quitara de problemas.